# Managing pipes by a central function in C

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to have a program with a fork that I'm trying to make to communicate between parent and child using pipes, but I want them to be managed by a central function (one for parent and one for child) and the communication to be done only through them, without giving the pipes ends as variables.
As seen in the code below, I have a function, function_manager and another that is message_to_father(char *s). I want all the functions from function_manager to be able to use message_to_father without needing to send pipe's "out" end as parameter to each of them, and then call message_to_father with that parameter. Is there a way to make message_to_father to know to use the pipes without parameters?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

//son

void message_to_father(char *s){
    // write(out, s, 19);
}

/*
//version that I don't want
void message_to_father(int out, char *s){
    // write(out, s, 19);
}
*/

void function_manager(int in, int out){
    //function_1(p1, p2, ...) //This would be better
    //function_2(out, p1, p2) // I don't want like this
    //function_3()
}

//parent

void message_to_son(char *s){
    // write(out, s, 19);
}

void user_interface_manager(int in, int out){

}

void initialize(){
    int pipe_father_to_son[2], pipe_son_to_father[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pipe (pipe_father_to_son);
    pipe (pipe_son_to_father);
    pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork()");
            exit(1);
            break;
        case 0:
            close(pipe_father_to_son[1]);
            close(pipe_son_to_father[0]);

            function_manager(pipe_father_to_son[0], pipe_son_to_father[1]);

            close(pipe_father_to_son[0]);
            close(pipe_son_to_father[1]);
            break;
        default:
            close(pipe_father_to_son[0]);
            close(pipe_son_to_father[1]);

            user_interface_manager(pipe_son_to_father[0], pipe_father_to_son[1]);

            close(pipe_father_to_son[1]);
            close(pipe_son_to_father[0]);
            wait(NULL);

    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're after, but you _can_ (but usually shouldn't) use global variables to convey information to functions.  If you think about it, `stdin` and `stdout` are global variables that are accessible for use when needed; maybe that's what you need for this code.  But why is there the resistance to doing the job properly — with the I/O channels passed to the functions?  Another option is to use `dup2()` to map the channels to standard I/O channels.  That also works.

Comment: Thanks, the method with dup2 is the one I used and it works great

Answer (score 0):

You're using C, not C++ or Java. That means one function, one task. You can't have a class with multiple functions and multiple tasks. And it also means you can't have implicit arguments.

So, no, what you want is not possible. The pipe to use must be an explicit argument, and to keep your design sane you must use multiple functions.

Comment: You can emulate classes in C, interfaces via vtbl and pointers to functions.